# How do I configure a Rails server in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on Mac High Sierra.  I would like to configure a Rails server for my existing Ruby project.  I have already imported the Ruby project into my workspace.  However, when adding a new server, the drop down list is empty ...

[image]

Not sure what else I need to do to add a server configuration.  Help is appreciated.

Comment: Just check if the `rails version` is correctly configured in the `environment.rb` file

Comment: What do you mean?  What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: what happens when you press "OK"  without changing anything?

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from Aptana Studio cannot recognize your project is a Rails project.

Right click on your project in left panel, choose `Properties` then choose `Project Natures` on the left side and check `Rails` on the right side, `Apply and close`. See my screenshot

[image]

Now, you will see your project in the Project dropdown

Anyway, I highly recommend you to use another IDE because Aptana seems to be out-dated. Its last release is more than 1 year ago. Especially for Rails, its support seem to be stopped at Rails 3 because its start script still lookup `rails` script in `script` folder instead of `bin` folder (so, you may also need to copy it from `bin` to `script` to be able to start the rails web server)